# Unable to clear the cart after paypal checkout Opencart 2.0.3.1

Tags: php, paypal, opencart2.x

I am working on opencart 2.0.3.1 and I run into this issue, when using Paypal standard payment method:

When a user checks out using paypal, **his cart does not get cleared** , even though the order gets placed.

The only way user's cart gets cleared is if he returns to the success page manually, however it's an unreliable method, because most users don't bother to comeback to merchant's site.

I am looking for a solution from one of these options:

- An opencart extension which adds a functionality to clear the cart during the payment process
- A block of code that clears the cart, so that I can paste it into the paypal payment processing file.

Comment: why don't you just write a simple line that redirects the user to the success page?

Comment: It does not work like that.

Comment: have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add this line of code

```
$this->cart->clear();
```

to this file: catalog/model/checkout/order.php

Answer (score 0):

Go to system/library/cart.php

Replace

```
$this->session->data['cart'] = array();
```

with

```
if (isset($this->session->data['customer_id'])) {
            $customer_id = $this->session->data['customer_id'];

            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET cart = '' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
        }
```

You can also write a Vqmod for it, if you do not feel comfortable hardcoding your system files.